# code to generate unique ID for face recognition using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I have written the code for face detection using OpenCV. I have video file and I am extracting images from the video based on specific given interval and running the face detection on each images. so there might be an instances where person is standing in front of camera for 5 minutes and image extraction interval is 1 min so for next 5 images the person would be the same. So how would i find out whether in each image person is same or the different one ? below is the code for face detect:

```
private static Rectangle[] DetectFace(Image<Bgr, Byte> image, string faceFileName)
        {           
            if (GpuInvoke.HasCuda)
            {
                using (GpuCascadeClassifier face = new GpuCascadeClassifier(faceFileName))
                {
                    using (GpuImage<Bgr, Byte> gpuImage = new GpuImage<Bgr, byte>(image))
                    using (GpuImage<Gray, Byte> gpuGray = gpuImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>())
                    {
                        Rectangle[] faceRegion = face.DetectMultiScale(gpuGray, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty);

                        return faceRegion;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Read the HaarCascade objects
                using (CascadeClassifier face = new CascadeClassifier(faceFileName))
                {

                    using (Image<Gray, Byte> gray = image.Convert<Gray, Byte>()) //Convert it to Grayscale
                    {
                        //normalizes brightness and increases contrast of the image
                        gray._EqualizeHist();                       

                        //Detect the faces  from the gray scale image and store the locations as rectangle
                        //The first dimensional is the channel
                        //The second dimension is the index of the rectangle in the specific channel
                        Rectangle[] facesDetected = face.DetectMultiScale(
                           gray,
                           1.1,
                           10,
                           new Size(filterWidth, filterHeight),
                           Size.Empty);

                        return facesDetected;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could construct a background image by computing the median of the last N frames.
From each new frame you can then subtract the background, so you only see the changes.
Try to **roughly**  recognize persons (by blob size or shape for example).
Based on the framerate of the camera you can then compute the average time, somebody spent in front of the camera.

I would like to be more precise, but we need some code of what you already tried...

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts, recognizing the person from each frame and these frames are generated from the video so they won't be exactly the same.